# Help for two values of x

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

I'm looking for help. Even if you just tell me the process rather than the answer.

Given that $y=10-3x^2$, find two values of $x$ for which $y=-17$.

How would I go about answering this?

Comment: Solve the equation $10-3x^2=-17$.

Answer (score 3):

Set $y = -17$, getting

$$-17 = 10 - 3x^2$$

Rearrange the equation to solve for $x^2$, and if possible take a square root.

Answer (score 2):

$$-17 = y = 10 - 3x^2$$
Rearranging ($x$'es to one side, the rest to the other) gives
$$3x^2 = 27$$
$$x^2 = 9$$
Taking the square root (which gives us two solutions) yields
$$x = \pm \sqrt{9} = \pm 3$$